# PHP DirectoryIterator Read From multi paths

Tags: php, html, arrays, path

i have php code read all pdfs file from path name: pdf_folder/2020/
and send it to my database

i need modify the code to read 3 paths :

1. pdf_folder/2020/
2. pdf_folder/2021/
3. pdf_folder/2022/

my code :

```
<?php
include('config.php');

        $extentions = array('pdf');

        $dir = new DirectoryIterator('pdf_folder/2020/');
        
       
        //SET Statues to Zero
        $sql5 = "UPDATE pdfs SET status=0";
        $query5 = mysqli_query($con,$sql5);

        foreach($dir as $fileinfo){

            if($fileinfo->isFile()){

                $extention = strtolower(pathinfo($fileinfo->getFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

                if(in_array($extention,$extentions)){

                    $name = $fileinfo->getFilename();

                    $sql2 = "SELECT name FROM pdfs WHERE name = '$name' LIMIT 1";
                    $query2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

                    if(mysqli_num_rows($query2) > 0){
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){
                            $name2 =  $row["name"];
                            $sql3 = "UPDATE pdfs SET status=1 WHERE name = '$name2' ";
                            $query3 = mysqli_query($con,$sql3);
                        }
                    }else{
                        $sql4 = "INSERT INTO pdfs(name) VALUES('$name')";
                        $query4 = mysqli_query($con,$sql4);
                    }

                     echo'
                    <a href="/php/test/'.$fileinfo->getFilename().'"> '.$fileinfo->getFilename().'</a><br>
                     ';

                }

            }

        }
```

I try this code but not working:

```
<?php

$dirs = scandir('pdf_folder');
$folders_to_process = ['2021', '2022', '2020'];
foreach ($dirs as $folder) {
    if ($folder == '..' || $folder == '.' || !is_dir($folder) || !in_array($folder, $folders_to_process)) continue;

    $extentions = array('pdf');

    $dir = new DirectoryIterator($folder);
```

Comment: considering the code you have so far I'm surprised that you are stuck with an outer loop

Comment: that mean ? please explian

Comment: I'll recommend you to run collect the directories to an array, then loop through it.

Comment: _Side note:_ Read [how to prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) by using prepared statements with bound parameters instead of injecting variables directly into your queries. It's not just about security. If your data contains, for example, a single quote `'`, your query will break.

Comment: @zaghadon I don't have enough PHP experience

Comment: Where is `$dirfull` defined before you first use it in `foreach($dirfull as $fileinfo){`?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius sorry by mistake  $dir not $dirfull

Comment: @MosaabAhmad I have written an answer that can help you out faster. while my answer can put you on quick, I do hope you'll try to understand how it was solved and become better with PHP.

Comment: @zaghadon using `scandir` and `DirectoryIterator` together is overkill. Simply use `DirectoryIterator` otherwise you are needlessly scanning directories more than necessary

Comment: Right. I guess a simple loop on the $folder_to_process and concatenating it to the pdf_folder/ is a simpler approach. @ProfessorAbronsius

Comment: What Errors did you get when you tried the code? @MosaabAhmad

Comment: @MosaabAhmad You copied the answer and paste it, you didn't check to see that I reused your code which had its own error, because you're using the `$dirfull` variable which you didn't define anywhere. 

Change it to `$dir` and try again. Although as pointed out by @ProfessorAbronsius using `scandir()` and `DirectoryIterator` is an Overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to re-factor the code slightly to take advantage of `Prepared Statements` by creating the statements before you begin inspecting folders. The following uses an array of years to form the outer loop (mentioned) - and on each iteration of that loop the year changes so what was essentially your original code now operates on a different folder.

I have tested the following and it appears to work OK.

```
<?php

    include('config.php');
    
    # Folders for years of interest to scan
    $years=array(2020,2021,2022);
    
    # for the output
    $li=array();
    
    # Allowed file extensions
    $extensions = array('pdf');
    
    # The various SQL cmds used with placeholders where required for use within prepared statements
    $sql=(object)array(
        'status'    =>  'update `pdfs` set `status`=0',
        'select'    =>  'select `name` from `pdfs` where `name`=? limit 1',
        'update'    =>  'update `pdfs` set `status`=1 where `name` = `name`=?',
        'insert'    =>  'insert into `pdfs` ( `name` ) values ( ? )'
    );
    
    # The prepared statements
    $stmt=(object)array(
        'status'    =>  $con->prepare( $sql->status ),
        'select'    =>  $con->prepare( $sql->select ),
        'update'    =>  $con->prepare( $sql->update ),
        'insert'    =>  $con->prepare( $sql->insert )
    );
    
    # set all PDF status to zero & bind other statements to $name variable
    # in mySQLi this variable does not need exist at this stage, in PDO it does.
    $stmt->status->execute();
    $stmt->select->bind_param('s',$name);
    $stmt->update->bind_param('s',$name);
    $stmt->insert->bind_param('s',$name);
    
    
    
    # iterate through all the years and construct new folder path to scan
    foreach( $years as $year ){
        
        $dir=new DirectoryIterator( sprintf( '%s/pdf_folder/%s', __DIR__, $year ) );
        
        #iterate through the files found
        foreach( $dir as $info ){
            if( !$info->isDot() ){
                
                # is the file extension OK?
                $ext=strtolower( pathinfo( $info->getFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
            
                if( in_array( $ext, $extensions ) ){
                    
                    # the $name variable is now populated for the SQL prepared statements to execute.
                    $name=$info->getFilename();
                    
                    $stmt->select->execute();
                    $stmt->select->store_result();
                    
                    if( $stmt->select->num_rows > 0 ){
                        $stmt->update->execute();
                    }else{
                        $stmt->insert->execute();
                    }
                    
                    $li[]=sprintf('<li><a href="/pdf_folder/%2$d/%1$s" target="_blank">%1$s</a></li>', $name, $year );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    # print the HTML list of hyperlinks
    printf('<ul>%s</ul>',implode(PHP_EOL,$li));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [scandir()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir) function to collect the pdf_folder to an array, then loop through it and do your existing operation after checks.

For instance, this would help:

```
<?php

$dirs = scandir('pdf_folder');
$folders_to_process = ['2021', '2022', '2020'];
foreach ($dirs as $folder) {
    if ($folder == '..' || $folder == '.' || !is_dir($folder) || !in_array($folder, $folders_to_process)) continue;

    $extentions = array('pdf');

    $dir = new DirectoryIterator($folder);


    //SET Statues to Zero
    $sql5 = "UPDATE pdfs SET status=0";
    $query5 = mysqli_query($con, $sql5);

    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {

        if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {

            $extention = strtolower(pathinfo($fileinfo->getFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            if (in_array($extention, $extentions)) {

                $name = $fileinfo->getFilename();

                $sql2 = "SELECT name FROM pdfs WHERE name = '$name' LIMIT 1";
                $query2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);

                if (mysqli_num_rows($query2) > 0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
                        $name2 =  $row["name"];
                        $sql3 = "UPDATE pdfs SET status=1 WHERE name = '$name2' ";
                        $query3 = mysqli_query($con, $sql3);
                    }
                } else {
                    $sql4 = "INSERT INTO pdfs(name) VALUES('$name')";
                    $query4 = mysqli_query($con, $sql4);
                }

                echo '
                    <a href="/php/test/' . $fileinfo->getFilename() . '"> ' . $fileinfo->getFilename() . '</a><br>
                     ';
            }
        }
    }
}
```